# kendo angular 2 grid rtl header issue

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

while using the angular 2 grid in RTL, the fields are aligned correctly, but the header fields are not, both the content and the fields themselves.

you can do an easy test - just use the regular grid, and add dir="RTL" in the HTML tag, 
unless I am missing something and I need to add something else?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Grid component officially doesn't support RTL mode yet. You can keep track for the state of readiness of the packages here - https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/96